# Prevent Chrome from restoring form inputs on tab restoration after logging out

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session

It seems Chrome has a feature where it restores form inputs (if they've been edited) when restoring a tab (`ctrl + shift + t`). That's great, except when it's restoring form inputs from a previous session. When user "A" logs out and user "B" logs in and restores the closed tab from the previous user, any input field user "A" has edited gets "restored", so essentially user "B" can view any data edited by user "A".

Is there a header I can send to prevent this from happening? Or is there a way I can detect that this happened via JavaScript and reload the page at least so the inputs can "reset"? (although the JavaScript solution wouldn't be ideal since it wouldn't be sufficient to protect sensitive data... user "B" could just disable JavaScript and get full access)

**Refreshing the page does not cause this issue and therefore any question about page refreshing is not a duplicate of this question. This question is strictly concerning tab restoration using `ctrl + shift + t`**